# ctrl-c [SIGINT] not working with Grunt while using grunt-shell

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-shell

If I use Grunt Task Runner with [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell), I'm not able to exit the grunt using ctrl-c [SIGINT].

```js
grunt.registerTask('serve', [
  'less',
  'autoprefixer',
  'shell:hologram', // grunt-shell task
  'connect:livereload',
  'watch'
]);
```

Here is how the shell is configured:

```js
grunt.initConfig({

...

  shell: {
    options: {
      failOnError: false
    },
    hologram: {
      command: 'bundle exec hologram'
    },
  },

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I run Grunt from Git Bash. And my solution was to update to the latest version of git bash and exit with **CTRL+SHIFT+C**.
It is very likely that **CTRL+SHIFT+C** will suffice (even with older versions).